# How do I save preferences for my VSTO plugin?

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

I've written a VSTO plugin for MS Project 2007 which basically just publishes Project data to our Sharepoint portal.  To do this, the user has to enter in the sharepoint site name into our plugin everytime that they want to publish.

How do I persist this information so that the user only has to enter the information once?  Ideally, I'd like to save it as part of the Project file so that it's portable from user to user.  If that's not possible, I'll settle for it just persisting on a single user's machine.

The best solution I have so far, is to just store a mapping of Project filenames to Sharepoint sites in the User's temp directory, but that just doesn't seem like the cleanest way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could store it using IsolatedStorage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx